# Alternativa para no usar CROSS JOIN

Tags: sql-server, join

Tengo 2 tablas :

```
select Cliente, CodigoOp into Tabla1
from
(
          select 59666 Cliente, 1853 CodigoOp
union all select 59666  ,1975
union all select 59666  ,2344
)T

select Cliente , CodigOp, Op into Tabla2
from
(
          select 59666  Cliente , 1853  CodigOp, 8519 Op
union all select 59666  ,1853   ,9470
union all select 59666  ,1853   ,9472
union all select 59666  ,1853   ,10399
union all select 59666  ,1975   ,9006
)t
```

Y básicamente necesito generar el  producto cartesiano de las dos tablas.

Tal como se muestra a continuación:

```
Cliente CodigoOp    Op1     Op2
------- --------    -----   -----
59666   1853        8519    8519
59666   1853        NULL    9006
59666   1853        9470    9470
59666   1853        9472    9472
59666   1853        10399   10399
59666   1975        NULL    8519
59666   1975        9006    9006
59666   1975        NULL    9470
59666   1975        NULL    9472
59666   1975        NULL    10399
59666   2344        NULL    8519
59666   2344        NULL    9006
59666   2344        NULL    9470
59666   2344        NULL    9472
59666   2344        NULL    10399
```

Para conseguirlo utilice el siguiente script:

```
select  
         d1.Cliente, d1.CodigoOp, d2.Op,d1.Op 
from
(

    select  b.Cliente, b.CodigOp, a.CodigoOp, b.Op
    from
    (
        select 
             Cliente, CodigoOp
        from Tabla1  
    )a
    cross apply 
    (
        select 
             b.Cliente, b.CodigOp, b.Op
            from Tabla1 a
            left join Tabla2 b
            on a.CodigoOp = b.CodigOp
            where b.CodigOp is not null  
    )b 
)d1
left join 
(
    select a.Cliente,a.CodigoOp,b.Op
    from Tabla1 a
    left join Tabla2 b
    on a.Cliente = b.Cliente and a.CodigoOp = b.CodigOp
    where b.CodigOp is not null  

)d2
on d1.Cliente = d2.Cliente
and d1.CodigoOp = d2.CodigoOp
and d1.Op = d2.Op
order by d1.Cliente, d1.CodigoOp, d1.Op
```

El problema que se me presento es que, en mis tablas reales tengo 20,000 registros en Tabla1 y mas de 200 ,000 en Tabla2 lo que hace demasiado costoso la utilización de las opciones mas comunes:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1, t2

SELECT *
FROM t1
CROSS JOIN t2 

SELECT *
FROM t1
CROSS APPLY t2
```

Que otra alternativa puedo usar para generar el resultado que necesito.

Comment: o sea, vos queres de resultado 4 billones de registros.. y decis que es costoso??? y si.. va a ser costoso y largo.. estas buscando una opcion que no sea sql o que cosa? porque veo que probaste de todo....

Comment: gracias ... pues, quizás alguna forma que escapara de mi experiencia, que pudiera hacer un poco mas eficiente u optimizado el proceso.

Comment: En SQL generar una tabla de 4 billones de registro, va a demorar y va a ser costoso para el servidor, no importa de la forma que lo generes. Si quieres una opinión, por ahí podés descargar las dos tablas como archivos planos, y generar el cartesiano con alguna otra  herramienta, va a demorar, pero al menos descongestionas el servidor.

Comment: Me parece, al final lo que  buscaba era descongestionar el servidor ...gracias.